# Resize ADFS 3.0 SSO Page in Salesforce1 for iPad

Tags: salesforce1-app, single-sign-on, federated-authentication, ipad

We have single sign-on configured with ADFS 3.0 and everything seems to be working correctly except the ADFS login page does not resize correctly inside the Salesforce1 app on an iPad.  The whole page is loaded into an iPhone size window and users have to swipe the screen over to enter their login credentials.  All other devices seem to be scaling correctly.  Any ideas about what can be done to have the ADFS login screen automatically resize for the credentials on an iPad?  Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

[image]

Comment: We did the same thing, and we do not observe this behavior. However, we do use the stock sidebar image.